# Symfony webpack encore twig functions not working

Tags: symfony, twig, webpack-encore

I am generating static html pages using twig in a Symfony 4 project. Am trying to generate multiple pages at the same time with a simple loop and the Twig render function. Code looks like this:

```
foreach ($pages as $page) {
  $html = $this->twig->render('template', $page);
  $fileSystem->dumpFile('fileName', $html);
}
```

In the template am using, I load assets via webpack encore twig functions `encore_entry_script_tags` and `encore_entry_link_tags`.

The problem I face is that the assets are **loaded** for the **first** generated page but not the others ! The generated html content does not contain script and style tags.

I thought about possible Twig cache problem so I set the cache to false but that didn't solve the problem. Also, the problem is gone when I use the standard twig function `{{ asset() }}` instead of webpack enore twig functions.

Any ideas ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem found and solved. Check this [link](https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore-bundle/issues/33) out for details. It's kinda a 'bug', the team still working on at the time I write this. A workaround is presented on the link.

Comment: Thanks for answering yourself. That info could be useful for others