# Symfony 4.4 Webpack Encore: tags won't appear

Tags: webpack, symfony4

I'm migrating a Symfony 3.x project to 4.4. Currently I'm working on migrating the Twig templates and their assets to Flex (already done) and Webpack Encore (in the process).

As described in the [Webpack Encore documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/frontend/encore/simple-example.html) I replaced all calls to `assert()` with `encore_entry_script_tags()` and `encore_entry_link_tags()` accordingly, adding entrypoints to the `webpack.config.js` to group all the assets together in the webpack as they were grouped in the Twig files before.

I managed to get this working for the login page. There are two entrypoints `app` and `login` that feature a JavaScript file each which imports all required SCSS and JavaScripts files. `app` is used in a generic `layout.html.twig` and `login` is used in the login page's specific `login.html.twig`. `login.html.twig` includes `layout.html.twig` so that both assets are included in the HTML output.

Now I wanted to migrate a second page that is put together by multiple Twig templates. As with the login page I put all its requirements as imports into new JavaScript files, created entrypoints in the `webpack.config.js` for them and applied these entrypoints in the respective Twig templates. This is working as well: the `script` and `style` tags are generated in the HTML data.

The weird thing is that while the Twig templates of the second page include `layout.html.twig` just like the login page does the `app` entrypoint does not appear in the HTML output. I surrounded the `encore_entry_*_tags` in the `layout.html.twig` with HTML comments to ensure that the Twig block is processed. The comments appear, yet without the actual `script` and `style` tags. First I thought I screwed it up somehow so I logged out to check whether the login page is working properly. It does, the appropriate tags appear in the HTML output.

I also tried rebuilding the assets over and over again (`yarn encore dev`; no errors) but the missing tags won't appear in the second page.

Login page HTML source excerpt:

```
<!-- banana: styles@app -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/vendors~app.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/app.css">
<!-- /banana: styles@app -->

[...]

<!-- banana: scripts@app -->
<script src="/build/runtime.js"></script>[... imported dependencies ...]<script src="/build/vendors~app.js"></script><script src="/build/app.js"></script>
<!-- /banana: scripts@app -->

<!-- banana: scripts@login -->
[... imported dependencies ...]<script src="/build/login.js"></script>
<!-- /banana: scripts@login -->
```

Second page HTML source excerpt:

```
<!-- banana: styles@app -->

<!-- /banana: styles@app -->

<!-- banana: styles@leaflet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/leaflet.css">
<!-- /banana: styles@leaflet -->

<!-- banana: styles@another.entrypoint -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="another.entrypoint.css">
<!-- /banana: styles@another.entrypoint -->

[...]

<!-- banana: scripts@app -->

<!-- /banana: scripts@app -->

<!-- banana: scripts@leaflet -->
[... imported dependencies ...]<script src="/build/leaflet.js"></script>
<!-- /banana: scripts@leaflet -->

<!-- banana: scripts@another.entrypoint -->
<script src="/build/another.entrypoint.js"></script>
<!-- /banana: scripts@another.entrypoint -->
```

I double checked with the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/frontend/encore/simple-example.html#page-specific-javascript-or-css-multiple-entries) because at first I thought that the `encore_entry_*_tags` might overwrite each other, but:

> Now, the checkout page will contain all the JavaScript and CSS for the app entry (because this is included in base.html.twig and there is the {{ parent() }} call) and your checkout entry.

This is exactly what does not happen in case of the second page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

So apparently the behaviour of `assert()` and `encore_entry_*_tags()` appears to be different. The issue in my case is caused by another template which includes `layout.html.twig`. This other template happens to be rendered previously although it is used conditionally (that is it's not used in my example).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54481716/6256153) to a similar question helped me getting on the right track. As it seems Webpack Encore will not output the `script` and `style` tag twice (which under normal circumstances makes absolutely sense). Therefore my task is now to rewrite the code so that other templates will only be rendered if they're actually going to be used - in which case it's fine for them to "steal" the tags.